# What is the role of lactic acid bacteria (such as L. acidophilus and L. bulgaricus) in glycolysis during yogurt fermentation?

Tags: bacteriology, fermentation, carbohydrates, ph

I am trying to prove that an increase in monosaccharides (glucose, fructose, galactose) that have been added to milk during fermentation will result in a decreased pH. My current argument is:

"The increase in the concentration of Phoenix Dactylifera is representative of an increase in the disaccharide, sucrose, and the monosaccharides, glucose and fructose — the primary sugars in date palm. This source of sugars adds to the natural sugar content already found in low-fat milk, which are lactose molecules composed of glucose and galactose. As such, more energy from these carbohydrates are available in the process of glycolysis, where LAB facilitate the conversion of six-carbon sugars like glucose, fructose, and galactose into pyruvate. This creates a greater frequency of glycolysis reactions, resulting in a greater overall yield of pyruvate molecules which can be converted into lactic acid. Hence, the increase in overall production of lactic acid increases acidity in the yoghurt and, thus, the pH."

What can I fix with my answer?